# Same PyObject for a shared_ptr C++ object

Tags: python, c++, c++11, boost, ffi

I have a similar problem as in this [mail](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/cplusplus-sig/2015-March/017234.html). I want that every time I return the same C++ managed object to Python, I get the same `PyObject`. With the standard converter I get always a new wrapper-`PyObject`. The solution should fulfill the following requirements:

- `get() == get()` (the Python object is always equal, whatever function returns the same C++ object)
- `get()` is `get()`
- The same is valid for any objects returned in containers (which the solution from the mail lacks) `getArray()[0] == get()`
- I can instance attributes (`get().new_var = "xx"` -> `get().new_var == "xx"`)

I wrote a template converter which takes as input a `shared_ptr`. It looks in a static map, if this `shared_ptr` is already returned, than it returns the existing `PyObject`, else a new one is created. I haven't found a solution there I can automatically remove unused objects.

In this case, I added a function to manually remove an entry. This works because the object is managed in C++ and I can intercept than the object should be removed from the C++ side. If Python has still a reference to this object, it's ok to wait for the GC to collect the Python side and implicitly remove the C++ object. If the last reference is removed in Python, the `PyObject` is still valid, because the map holds still a reference. Also , as long as the `PyObject` inside the map exists, the C++ object cannot be removed from the heap.

I made a couple of test, which shows the validity, that can be found [here](https://github.com/CymricNPG/cpython/blob/same_pyobject/python/test_module.py).

The usage is:

```
boost::python::to_python_converter<boost::shared_ptr<A>,
        c_ptr_to_cached_python<A>>();
```

Is the following code enough to fulfill the requirements for any C++ class wrapped in a `shared_ptr`? Is the `PyObject` generation valid and can it be improved?

```
#pragma once
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

template<typename C_CLASS>
using storage_map = std::map<C_CLASS*, PyObject*>;

template<typename C_CLASS>
storage_map<C_CLASS>* getCachedObjects() {
    static storage_map<C_CLASS> *storage = new storage_map<C_CLASS>();
    return storage;
}

template<typename C_CLASS>
using c_sptr = boost::shared_ptr<C_CLASS>;

template<typename C_CLASS>
using py_ptr = typename boost::python::pointee<boost::shared_ptr<C_CLASS>>::type;

template<typename C_CLASS>
PyObject * createObject(const c_sptr<C_CLASS>& obj) {
    return boost::python::objects::make_ptr_instance<py_ptr<C_CLASS>,
            boost::python::objects::pointer_holder<c_sptr<C_CLASS>,
                    py_ptr<C_CLASS>>>::execute(obj);
}

template<typename C_CLASS>
void cleanMap() {
    auto map = getCachedObjects<C_CLASS>();
    for (auto it = map->begin(); it != map->end();) {
        auto py_obj = it->second;
        Py_DecRef(py_obj);
        map->erase(it++);
    }
}

template<typename C_CLASS>
void removeObject(const c_sptr<C_CLASS>& obj) {
    auto map = getCachedObjects<C_CLASS>();
    auto raw_ptr = obj.get();
    auto it = map->find(raw_ptr);
    if (it == map->end()) {
        throw std::logic_error("Object was already removed.");
    }
    auto py_obj = it->second;
    Py_DecRef(py_obj);
    map->erase(it);
}

template<typename C_CLASS>
struct c_ptr_to_cached_python {
    static PyObject* convert(const c_sptr<C_CLASS> &obj) {
        auto raw_ptr = obj.get();
        auto map = getCachedObjects<C_CLASS>();
        auto it = map->find(raw_ptr);
        if (it == map->end()) {
            auto py_obj = createObject<C_CLASS>(obj);
            (*map)[raw_ptr] = py_obj;
            Py_INCREF(py_obj); // Increment to store in map
            return py_obj;
        } else {
            auto old_py_obj = it->second;
            Py_INCREF(old_py_obj);
            return old_py_obj;
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand all the premises of this question. My kneejerk reaction was, "Would it help if you could assume that `C_CLASS` derived from `std::enable_shared_from_this<C_CLASS>`? Is it in your power to make that an invariant in your codebase?" If so, I would even go a step further and ask whether you should just write an `enable_PyObject_from_this<C_CLASS>` along the same lines.

---

Anyway, I see a bit of reducible complexity in your code, I think.

```
template<typename C_CLASS>
using py_ptr = typename boost::python::pointee<boost::shared_ptr<C_CLASS>>::type;
```

Isn't this just a really complicated way of saying

```
template<typename T> using py_ptr = T;
```

(since `pointee<ptr<T>>::type` is `ptr<T>::element_type` is `T` by definition)?  And then you use it in contexts like

```
template<typename C_CLASS>
PyObject * createObject(const c_sptr<C_CLASS>& obj) {
    return boost::python::objects::make_ptr_instance<py_ptr<C_CLASS>,
            boost::python::objects::pointer_holder<c_sptr<C_CLASS>,
                    py_ptr<C_CLASS>>>::execute(obj);
}
```

which ought to be more like

```
template<typename T>
PyObject *createObject(const std::shared_ptr<T>& obj) {
    using namespace boost::python::objects;
    return make_ptr_instance<T, pointer_holder<shared_ptr<T>, T>>::execute(obj);
}
```

Even that *looks* more complicated than it feels like it ought to be, but I'm not finding much documentation about what `make_ptr_instance` is supposed to do (or for that matter why the second template type parameter to `pointer_holder` isn't defaulted).

---

I see you use `Py_INCREF` (all caps) but `Py_DecRef` (camel case). This suggests to the reader that something really subtle (and thus dangerous) is happening here — or else of course you'd be consistently using `Py_IncRef/DecRef` or `Py_INCREF/DECREF` (both of which are provided by the underlying library). But is the reader's inference correct? **Are** you really doing something subtle and dangerous? Or are you just mixing styles because you felt like it?

---

Are you at all worried that `getCachedObjects<Base>()` returns a completely different map from `getCachedObjects<Derived>()`, even though I might have a `std::shared_ptr<Base> b` and a `std::shared_ptr<Derived> d` such that `b == d`?